# it dentro do .addSuccessListener

Tags: android, firebase

estou utilizando o Firestore para um projeto em que faço uma consulta de usuário, no entanto esta dando problema quando pego o objeto "it" dentro do método .addOnSuccessListener, no it.nome aparece um erro de Unresolved Reference:

```
var firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Usuarios").document(evento.host!!).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                txt_nome_evento_exibir.setText(evento.nome)
                txt_data_evento_exibir.setText(evento.data)
                txt_descricao_evento_exibir.setText(evento.descricao)
                txt_local_evento_exibir.setText(evento.local)
                txt_host_evento_exibir.setText(it.nome)
                txt_horario_evento_exibir.setText(evento.horario_inicio)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está dando esse problema porque o "it" é um DocumentSnapshot, tem que transformar ele em objeto:

```
var firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Usuarios").document(evento.host!!).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                var aux = it.toObject(SeuObjeto::class.java)
                txt_nome_evento_exibir.setText(evento.nome)
                txt_data_evento_exibir.setText(evento.data)
                txt_descricao_evento_exibir.setText(evento.descricao)
                txt_local_evento_exibir.setText(evento.local)
                txt_host_evento_exibir.setText(aux!!.nome)
                txt_horario_evento_exibir.setText(evento.horario_inicio)
            }
```